# Gii production not found (404)

Tags: yii2

I have table tb_barang.

1. So I create model **Barang** with enable table_prefix.
2. Then, I create crud, with model **app\models\Barang** and controller: **app\Controllers\BarangController**

I have use htaccess and enable pretty_url and everything is fine. ex 
*localhost/yii_app/web/site*.

But when pointing to localhost/yii_app/web/barang
its

```
Not Found (#404)
```

Why gii failed ?

Comment: show your .htaccess! Are you using yii2 advanced?

Comment: i try to not use .htaccess. Still not work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you.

`app\models\Barang` ==>  model name

`app\Controllers\BarangController` ==> controller name

`views\barang\index.php` ==> inside views folder create barang folder then your index.php like this this order